# Is there a way to create a hollowed circle in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe, virtual-reality, webvr

I'm trying to build a [Flower of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlapping_circles_grid) VR example using A-Frame.

The closest thing that I found is using the `opacity` property in `<a-circle>`.

Is there a way to create just the border of the circle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it fits your use case but you could use a cylinder with a small height:
https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/primitives/a-cylinder.html

Or a tube:
https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/primitives

Or just a flat plane with png texture with a circle with transparency